# Why does my laptop freeze up when I dock it?

Tags: laptop, freeze, dell-latitude, docking-station

I have a Dell Latitude D520. First with Windows XP and now with Windows 7, **it completely freezes/locks up if I dock it while it's awake**. If I hibernate/sleep, dock, then wake/resume, everything's fine.

I installed the Dell Notebook System Software for Vista (No Win7 version available) and updated the bios to the latest version but the problem persists.

As long as I remember to put this thing in standby before I dock it, it's extremely reliable--it survives my daily commute and heavy use and typically only reboots a few times a month.

Any other ideas for things I can try?

Answer (score 1):

Does it do this in Safe Mode?  It's possible that there's something running that freaks out when it sees that additional hardware show up, and that's the easiest test to do to see about that.

Possibly obvious, but does it do this when there's NOTHING attached to the dock except the machine itself?  Does it make a difference if the battery isn't in the laptop (disclaimer, I'm unsure if you can dock these with an AC cable attached because I forget the form factor of the dock, so disregard if this isn't possible).

Barring anything like that, it may be an electrical issue with the docking connector.  I'd call Dell and see if there's a known problem - Thinkpad docks used to have a problem like this due to some bare metal locking connectors, the fix being to put rubber caps on them.

Comment: Good ideas. I'll check